# In pandas, how to replace subdataframe by another subdataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following 2 pandas dataframes (the column names are same, but df1 contains the data for 2019 and df2 contains the data for 2020):

df1

```
DateTime            Col1    Col2      Col3
2019-10-14 00:00:00 5.35    201.75    16.50
2019-10-14 00:10:00 4.90    187.65    16.49
2019-10-14 00:20:00 4.80    186.89    16.48
2019-10-14 00:30:00 5.12    177.48    16.46
2019-10-14 00:40:00 5.83    332.94    6.45
```

df2

```
DateTime            Col1    Col2       Col3
2020-10-14 00:00:00 5.35    231.75    14.50
2020-10-14 00:10:00 6.90    217.15    14.49
2020-10-14 00:20:00 6.80    181.69    14.46
2020-10-14 00:30:00 7.12    175.48    14.48
2020-10-14 00:40:00 5.83    212.95    15.45
```

I need to substitute the rows of df1 between 2020-10-14 00:10:00 and 2020-10-14 00:30:00 (including) by the rows from df2.

This is the expected result (the 2nd, 3rd and 4th rows are taken from df2, while the DateTime values remain from df1):

```
DateTime            Col1    Col2      Col3
2019-10-14 00:00:00 5.35    201.75    16.50
2019-10-14 00:10:00 6.90    217.15    14.49
2019-10-14 00:20:00 6.80    181.69    14.46
2019-10-14 00:30:00 7.12    175.48    14.48
2019-10-14 00:40:00 5.83    332.94    6.45
```

How can I do it? Is it possible to apply panda's "where" here?

Comment: There are 3 solutions - are there same index and same length of Data in both DataFrames? If yes, use any solution. If need match by `dates` only my match by datetimes. Another matched by RangeIndex

Comment: @jezrael: Yes, indices might be different in real dataframes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution for match by `DatetimeIndex` with subtract one year for dates in year `2020`, so matching by year `2019` rows in another DataFrame:

```
df22 = df2.set_index('DateTime').loc['2020-10-14 00:10:00':'2020-10-14 00:30:00']
df1 = df1.set_index('DateTime')

df = df22.rename(lambda x: x - pd.DateOffset(years=1)).combine_first(df1)
print (df)
                     Col1    Col2   Col3
DateTime                                
2019-10-14 00:00:00  5.35  201.75  16.50
2019-10-14 00:10:00  6.90  217.15  14.49
2019-10-14 00:20:00  6.80  181.69  14.46
2019-10-14 00:30:00  7.12  175.48  14.48
2019-10-14 00:40:00  5.83  332.94   6.45
```

Alternative with `update`:

```
df22 = df2.set_index('DateTime').loc['2020-10-14 00:10:00':'2020-10-14 00:30:00']
df1 = df1.set_index('DateTime')

df22 = df22.rename(lambda x: x - pd.DateOffset(years=1))

df1.update(df22)
print (df1)
                     Col1    Col2   Col3
DateTime                                
2019-10-14 00:00:00  5.35  201.75  16.50
2019-10-14 00:10:00  6.90  217.15  14.49
2019-10-14 00:20:00  6.80  181.69  14.46
2019-10-14 00:30:00  7.12  175.48  14.48
2019-10-14 00:40:00  5.83  332.94   6.45
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that pd.DateOffset(years=1) reduced 2020 by 1 to get 2019?

Comment: @Fluxy - Exactly, for match `2019` year by `2020` year

Answer (score 2):

You can use `where`:

```
df1['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['DateTime'])
df2.where(df1['DateTime'].between('2019-10-14 00:10:00',
                                  '2019-10-14 00:30:00'),
          df1)
```

or `mask`:

```
df1['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['DateTime'])
df1.mask(df1['DateTime'].between('2019-10-14 00:10:00',
                                 '2019-10-14 00:30:00'),
         df2)
```

output:

```
              DateTime  Col1    Col2   Col3
0  2019-10-14 00:00:00  5.35  201.75  16.50
1  2020-10-14 00:10:00  6.90  217.15  14.49
2  2020-10-14 00:20:00  6.80  181.69  14.46
3  2020-10-14 00:30:00  7.12  175.48  14.48
4  2019-10-14 00:40:00  5.83  332.94   6.45
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `loc`:

```
>>> df1.loc[df1['DateTime'].ge('2019-10-14 00:10:00') & df1['DateTime'].le('2019-10-14 00:30:00'), ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']] = df2
>>> df1
              DateTime  Col1    Col2   Col3
0  2019-10-14 00:00:00  5.35  201.75  16.50
1  2019-10-14 00:10:00  6.90  217.15  14.49
2  2019-10-14 00:20:00  6.80  181.69  14.46
3  2019-10-14 00:30:00  7.12  175.48  14.48
4  2019-10-14 00:40:00  5.83  332.94   6.45
>>>
```

Comment: @jezrael It matches the OPs desired output.

Comment: @jezrael: Could you please specify which data problem do you refer to? Thanks!!

Comment: @U12-Forward - added under question what is problem here